# SQLAlchemy still able to get object from session after deletion

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I have an endpoint to delete an object from my database. I delete it with the following code:

```
my_object = Object.query.get(id)
db.session.delete(my_object)
db.session.commit()
return json.dumps({'success': True}
```

I have an API test to test the endpoint where I create an object and then use the endpoint to delete it. I am trying to assert after the deletion happens it isn't in the database.

```
my_object = MyObject()
db.session.add(my_object)
db.session.commit()
response = requests.delete('{}/my-object/{}'.format(
    os.environ.get('MY_URL'),
    my_object.id
))
self.assertTrue(response.json()['success']) // this passes
self.assertEqual(200, response.status_code) // this passes
result = db.session.query(MyObject).get(my_object.id)
print(result.id) // prints the id of the job even though it is deleted from the database
```

I think this is related to some SQLAlchemy session caching. I have tried `db.session.flush()`, `db.session.expire_all()` to no avail. The object is actually being deleted from the database. So I would expect the query result to be `None`.

I see this in the docs but haven't full wrapped my head around it. [when to commit and close a session](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_basics.html#when-do-i-construct-a-session-when-do-i-commit-it-and-when-do-i-close-it)

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Have you tried committing before the query but after the deletion? Or maybe opening a new session would be even cleaner.

Comment: Two question that could help to narrow this down: Do you run your server in the same process? Does your test framework use transactions to rollback the database to the previous state after every test?

Comment: @9000 I'm not sure I understand the first question. I can try opening a new session and see if that works.

Comment: @AdamByrtek I believe so. And yes I rollback the database transactions. I do this by running another query and then committing.

Comment: If the test framework opens its own transaction, then whatever transactions my happen inside it are sub-transaction, and whether they commit or roll back, is only visible inside the outer transaction. When the outer transaction is rolled back, all inner transactions are also rolled back. (This is why I avoid this approach when possible, and instead drop and reload tables before each test.)

Answer (score 5):

So in your test code, you add the object to a session and commit it. It gets saved to the db, and is your session's identity map.

Then you hit your app, it has it's own session. It deletes the object and commits, now it's gone from the db. But...

Your previous session doesn't know anything about this, and when you use a .get(), it will give back what's in its identity map: a Python object with an ID. It won't refetch unless you close the session or force a refresh from the DB (I can't remember OTOH how to do this, but you can, it's in the docs somewhere). If you used a clean third session, it would have a fresh identity map and would not be holding onto a reference to the python object so you'd get what you expect, ie. no result. This is by design because the Identity Map allows SQLAlchemy to chain a bunch of changes together into one optimal SQL query that is only fired when you commit.

So yeah, you're seeing the fetch from the Identity Map which is still alive. (You can even pop it open in the interactive interpreter and poke around) And it makes sense, because say you have two threads of different web requests and one is part way doing some longer lived stuff with an object when another request deletes the object. The first thread shouldn't barf on the Python code working with the object, because that would just trigger random exceptions wherever you were in the code. It should just think that it can do its thing, and then fail *on commit*, triggering a rollback.

HTH

Comment: So I have two sessions. One in the test and one in the app when I hit it with the request. So I would need to remove the session and create a new one in order to test this?

Comment: This was helpful to think about in this way. I wasn't able to figure refreshing from the database. I tried `db.session.refresh(db.session.query(MyObject).get(my_object.id))` but this would return `None` even if the object existed in the database.

Comment: Not tested or anything. But if you check sqlalchemy documentation a lot of examples uses db.session.close() in order to probably avoid what you describing. As a side note, it feels like your issue was more about how you setup sqlalchemy (and/or usage) so by extension this probably could be rectified upper in the chain of calls.

Answer (score 1):

db.session.expunge_all()

"Remove all object instances from this Session..."

http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session.expunge_all

Or simple trigger after each request db.session.remove()

For example in Flask with SQLAlchemy scoped_session:

```
@app.teardown_appcontext
def shutdown_session(exception=None):
   db.session.remove()
```

"The scoped_session.remove() method, as always, removes the current Session associated with the thread, if any. However, one advantage of the threading.local() object is that if the application thread itself ends, the “storage” for that thread is also garbage collected. So it is in fact “safe” to use thread local scope with an application that spawns and tears down threads, without the need to call scoped_session.remove(). However, the scope of transactions themselves, i.e. ending them via Session.commit() or Session.rollback(), will usually still be something that must be explicitly arranged for at the appropriate time, unless the application actually ties the lifespan of a thread to the lifespan of a transaction."

http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/contextual.html#thread-local-scope
http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/contextual.html#using-thread-local-scope-with-web-applications

Comment: I tried `db.session.expunge_all()` and I get a `DetachedInstanceError`. Saying the object is not bound to a session.

Answer (score 1):

After a fair amount of reading and testing I found creating a new session to be the easiest solution. I wasn't able to figure out how to refresh the record from the database even though the record was stale.

Here is some reading I did:

[when to commit and close a session](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_basics.html#when-do-i-construct-a-session-when-do-i-commit-it-and-when-do-i-close-it)

[is the session a cache](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_basics.html#is-the-session-a-cache)

[is the session thread safe](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_basics.html#is-the-session-thread-safe)

[understanding sqlalchemy session](http://pythoncentral.io/understanding-python-sqlalchemy-session/)

Here is how I solved the problem by creating a new db connection and session using `Flask-SQLAlchemy`:

```
[my other imports...]
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

[my other code...]

def test_it_should_delete_my_object(self):
    my_object = MyObject()
    db.session.add(my_object)
    db.session.commit()
    response = requests.delete('{}/my-object/{}'.format(
        os.environ.get('MY_URL'),
        my_object.id
    ))
    self.assertTrue(response.json()['success'])
    self.assertEqual(200, response.status_code)

    new_db = SQLAlchemy(app) // establishing a new connection
    result = new_db.session.query(MyObject).get(my_object.id) // by using a new
    self.assertIsNone(result)
```

Thank you all for the help. Gonna be doing more research on this.

Comment: Yeah, that's what you should do, close out sessions and create new ones. Creating sessions is cheap in SQLAlchemy. For what's it's worth, I don't recommend Flask-SQLAlchemy, I personally prefer to just use plain sqlalchemy. Flask-SQLAlchemy doesn't add a whole lot of convenience at the expense of magic. You see a *lot* of questions from people using Flask-SQLAlchemy who are confused about what the session management is doing.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I'll look into just using SQLAlchemy.

Comment: +1 for plain SQLAlchemy without Flask-SQLAlchemy. You be able to use sessions and models outside app. For example in some background tasks of DB maintenance modules. With Flask-SQLAlchemy you will need an app instance with app_context anywhere to use models.

Comment: although not exactly your use case, but I would also suggest reading about the `synchronize_session` parameter provided to the `.delete()` function. There are few strategies to perform a delete query regarding the deleted entities on the session.